# Weak dependence of a variable

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I asked the same question last week, but it seems it wasn't that clear and it was closed, so I try to expand it to explain better what I need. If I cannot do this, sorry in advance.

I have a variable $y$ that depends on some variables  $x_1 \in [x_{1,min},x_{1,max}]$, $x_2 \in [x_{2,min},x_{2,max}]$, $x_3 \in [x_{3,min},x_{3,max}]$, i.e. $y = y(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Does there exist a test to quantify how $x_1$, $x_2$ or $x_3$ make the value of $y$ to change?

As a simple example, $ y = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 $, with $x_1 \in [50,80]$, $x_2 \in [0,1]$, $x_3 \in [0,1]$. Clearly, the value of $y$ depends much more on $x_1$ than the other 2 variables. How do I quantify this dependence?

What I mean with weak dependence is the following: I want to detect which variable determines very small changes in y, i.e. in the previous example x2 and x3 makes y to vary less than x1 does.

The kind of problem that I will evaluate could be also nonlinear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Independence of a variable?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144692/independence-of-a-variable)

Comment: @Xi'an Please check on the first two rows I wrote above. I will delete the old one to continue here.

Comment: The previous question was closed by moderators. This one sounds almost exactly the same, so should be closed as well.

Comment: I agree that the previous question was kind of confusing. I added an example, that now seems to be clear (there is an answer to the question now). In this question I also added some explanations on what I want to measure. If you don't understand some points, I please you to ask me to clarify, instead of directly closing. Thank you so much for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you can assume that problem y=a+b_1*x_1+b_2*x_2+b_3*x_3 is linear in parameters then this quantification can be done via fetching elements from the parameter vector b.

Otherwise perhaps you have to assume some particular functional form and use non-linear least squares algorithm.

In any case you could get effect on y from the x variables via b parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in the example I made, the regression in the form you presented would give me b_1 = b_2 = b_3 = 1. How can I consider the larger values of x1?

Comment: No, it would not give so. Try yourself. Range of variation in x_1 is greater than in two other variables and it should show in your results.